# Memory leak regarding NSRange

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, nsrange

```
NSString *mob = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(mobNum, emailCounter);
                mob = [ApplicationSingleton FindMobileNumber:mob];
                if ([favos rangeOfString:mob].location != NSNotFound)
```

it gives below message when checking for memory leaks...

the receiver of message "rangeOfString:" is nil and returns a value of type NSRange that will be garbage

can anyone please help me...
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `favos` is nil. Make sure that the variable is set in all code paths, or check it for nil.

Comment: No dear i am assigning the value to it and it works perfeclty fine,just i want to get off with the memory leak warning

Comment: Did you try adding the nil check? Maybe the analyzer can't see that favos always will be assigned to.